# Как правильно прописывать стили?

Tags: css

Как правильно прописывать стили?

В zeplin написано:

Ситуация 1:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ситуация 2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

интересует именно написание `font-family` и `font-weight` для каждого из 2 случаев.

Comment: А что вас смущает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы имеете ввиду

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&subset=latin,cyrillic);

body {
font: bold 12px/20px 'Roboto',sans-serif;
}
```

вопрос немного непонянет

font-family: 'указывается стиль';

font-weight: 'указывается насыщенность шрифта(bold|bolder|lighter|normal|100|200|300|400|500|600|700|800|900)'

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, мне прислали шрифты museo-700, museo-500, и они  подключены уже.
в случае робото все понятно...
Вопрос, правильно ли я написала...
1 случай: 
font-family: MuseoSanSCyrl-700;
font-weight: bold;

2 случай:
font-family: MuseoSanSCyrl-500;
font-weight: 500;

именно по картинкам.

Comment: font-family: 'MuseoSanSCyrl-700'; font-weight: 700; font-family: 'MuseoSanSCyrl-500'; font-weight: 500

Comment: в названии шрифта указывается его насыщенность, т.е. font-weight: